# Which comes first, "Skip to main content", or disclaimer?

Tags: html, accessibility

Let's say I have a static website which I try to make accessible.

To this end, I include a "Skip to main content" link at the top.

I also want people to know what they're getting into, so I have a disclaimer message at the top.

The disclaimer message includes a JS-driven "hide" button, but this is not accessible (or visible) to users without JS.

Which do I put first, the link to #main, or the disclaimer message?

(goal 1) I want someone who is a new visitor to the site, with JS disabled, using TTS, to see the disclaimer first.

(goal 2) But if they've been before, It probably won't be helpful for them to hear the disclaimer every time they open a new page.

Is it possible to accomplish both goals?

If it wasn't static, and included a server-side element, I could have the {hide} link be server-side cookie-based, but that is not the case.

Edit: There was a comment, which I now regret flagging, saying that "99.999999% of users" (a statistic I question) have JS enabled, implying that the other 0.000001% do not matter. I disagree with this assessment, because I strongly believe in my goal of **accessibility to all 100% of users** visiting my site. While perhaps it is never attainable, I will not stop trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to accomplish both goals?

Since it sounds like the only tools available to you in this case are HTML and CSS, I would say no, it's not. So with that in mind…

I would add the skip link first. You could place the disclaimer between your skip link and your navigation. Though your disclaimer would be repeated on every page, it'd be no different than a nav bar at the top of your page that the user would have to listen to every time – that's why you have the skip link in the first place.

TTS users should be plenty aware that they may be missing important information if they click that link. I'm no legal expert, but I'd be willing to bet that you (or your company) are not going to be suddenly liable for damages because the disclaimer was not the literal first thing a TTS user hears when entering your website.

Answer (score -1):

> with JS disabled, using TTS,

100,1% (*) of users using text-to-speech do use Javascript. This includes blind people, people with vision loss, people with cognitive disorders, illiterate people or non native speakers, ...

Also note that, among them, a large part of people with disabilities will view (visually) your webpage. The "skip link" is also useful for people with physical disabilities when mouse navigation is complicated (parkinson disease, hemiplegia, ...).

The other ones (blind people) relying only on audio will not view your webpage visually but will still use a javascript compliant screenreader (Jaws, NVDA, Chromevox, VoiceOver, ...).

For instance, you can see WebAim survey where [JavaScript was enabled in the browsers of 100% of respondents.](https://webaim.org/projects/practitionersurvey2/)

(*) The 0,1% extra is because Javascript can help improving accessibility.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Are you trying to say that because this study found no users that were both TTS and noJS that they do not exist at all, ever?

Comment: @i-g Modern assistive technologies rely on the accessibility API provided by standard mainstream browsers which do support javascript. People may choose to disable javascript but that won't be due to their disabilities, but to a choice. A big part of modern accessibility is to do improve their comfort using javascript (dynamically setting aria attributes for instance).

Comment: And as a webmaster, it is my calling and desire to make my site accessible to the users who make that choice (to disable JS.) Anything less would be unwelcoming and lazy.

Comment: Also, can you please explain how more than 100% of users are browsing with JS enabled? I am confused.

Comment: @i-g "Web accessibility" focus on people with disabilities, not on technical choices made by users having no disabilities. Back in 1999 and WCAG 1, Web page were required to work without javascript, but WCAG 2 states that when Javascript is used it must be accessible, because all moderns screenreaders use Javascript, and people with disabilities do not want to suffer segregation by being required to consult alternate versions of websites.

Comment: Accessibility includes low-power devices, which sometimes cannot handle the additional CPU load of JS.

Low-power devices are used disproportionately by the disadantaged, like people living on lower-than-average incomes.

So by excluding no-JS users, I would basically be giving a big fuck-you to "poor" people, which I don't want to do.

Comment: @i-g You have to open another question for that. The current question is about JS and screenreaders, which won't be used on low-power devices...

Comment: Could you please substantiate the claim that low-power devices and screenreaders do not mix? You do not think there are any visually-impaired users with older devices out there?

Comment: @i-g You should really read that (other) Webaim survey https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey7/ It can answer many of your questions, more important than finding a screenreader working on low-power devices... (sorry I can't find any)

Comment: Thank you for the link, very interesting. I could find no mention of JS, however. Am I missing something?

Comment: @i-g As I try to explain, JS is a non-subject. What you see is that screenreaders are always used conjointly with a standard browser. People using screenreaders have no problem with the Javascript technology itself. The main goal of accessibility is to make websites accessible no matter the underlying technology. We can't, in 2019, ignore that nearly 99% of websites use Javascript. So having a nice website without Javascript is still a good thing (i'm a big fan and it will also improve SEO), but if you do use JS, you should know that screenreaders will also benefit from Javascript.

Comment: You have not proven that there are not any users out there that may wish to use a screenreader without javascript. Not only are you using a small sample size, but you are also overlooking the possibility of a chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: @i-g I'm sorry you missed the important part of my answer. I repeat : you can perfectly disable javascript, but that's a question not related to accessibility because screenreaders handle javascript. If your only concern is about people disabling javascript, we are no longer talking about people with disabilities using screenreaders.